# Binary mask in image space from point cloud data

Tags: matlab, binary-data, point-clouds, mathematical-morphology

Hy!

I have a point cloud representing walls and the floor of an indoor scene.
I projected the points of the floor on a plane. That means it's a "2d point cloud" now.
All z-coordinates are zero.

I have to deal with missing parts. My idea now is to fill the holes.
Is there a way to transform the points into the image space to create a 
binary mask? I would like to use techniques like: "imfill" in Matlab...

Thanks

Edit:

To make it more clear, I will explain an simple example. I have points in 2D. After I made a triangulation, I can access each triangle. For each triangle I create a binary mask with poly2mask(), and each mask I write to an final image.
Here is an example: 
[image]

Now I can use morphological operations on the image.
E.G: Here is an more complex example, where the triangulation gives me bad results:

[image]

To fill the hole on the right side, I could use morphological operation.
My problem: The points can be negative, and the distance between the triangles can be very small (E.g.: x coordinates of triangle: (1.12 1.14 1.12), will give me the point 1 in the image space

Comment: What exactly is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to get a 3d model of a room. My idea is to calculate the floor plane, and create the walls by extruding the edges on the boundary. The problem is, that the point cloud (of the floor) has holes and missing parts.

Comment: I think it would help if you could include a plot of your data, or maybe the data themselves.

Comment: Is `poly2mask` helps you? I also didn't realy understand your purpose...

Comment: I will post an image soon to make it clear. Poly2mask was my first idea. The problem is, that i have problems with the right scale. The values can be negative and they are not uniform distributed. After i posted a image it should get clear. Thx

Comment: Looks like you want to calculate the bounding polygon from cloud of points projected to the floor, to get the boundaries of the walls of the room? This can be done by the convex hull i think. Images would help.